# Why won't the last array value be returned?

Tags: javascript

I have an array with several values and I want to get value stored in the multiple of 3. So, in this case the new array should be `13` and `28`. However, I'm only getting `13`.

Code:

```
    // array1 --> [ '5', '10', '13', '15', '20', '28' ]
    var trueLength = array1.length;
    var iCount = 1;
    for(var i = 0; i < trueLength;) {
        if(iCount % 3 != 0) {
            array1.shift();
        } else if (iCount % 3 == 0) {
            array2.push(array1[i]);
            array1.shift();
        }
        iCount += 1;
        if(iCount == trueLength) break;
    }
```

Output:

```
[ '13' ]
```

I don't see anything logically wrong for it to only output `13` which makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array1.shift();` will remove the first element of the array. If you do this while iterating over `iCount`, you'll be skipping over some elements of the array, since you're both removing items and incrementing the index being iterated over.

Just filter the array by the modulo of the index being iterated over.

```js
const arr = [ '5', '10', '13', '15', '20', '28' ];
const result = arr.filter((_, i) => i % 3 === 2);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Could you explain to me the filter, I don't understand it. If that's okay with you

Comment: When the value returned in the callback is truthy, the item being iterated over is included in the result, otherwise it's excluded from the result. `i % 3 === 2` will evaluate to true on indicies 2, 5, 8, and so on.

Comment: ah right, because we start from position `0` and not `1` so it will evaluate true indices starting from `2` and also, if i were to change `i % 3 === 2` to `i % 4 === 2` so it would grab the 3rd 6th, 9th and so on index correct?

Comment: Yes, that's how it'd work

Comment: Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 0):

you got little logical problem at `break` condition
this would do

```js
var array1 = ['5', '10', '13', '15', '20', '28'];
var array2 =[];

var trueLength = array1.length;
var iCount = 1;
    for(var i = 0; i < trueLength;) {
        if(iCount % 3 != 0) {
           
            array1.shift();
        } else if (iCount % 3 == 0) {
              console.log(iCount);
            array2.push(array1[i]);
            array1.shift();
        }
        iCount += 1;
        if(iCount == trueLength+1) break;
    }
    
    console.log(array2[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like ti use the pattern of shift and neccessary pushign the value, you could use two variables to keep track of the length of the rest items and another for calculate the remainder..

```js
const
    array = ['5', '10', '13', '15', '20', '28'];
    
let i = 1,
    l = array.length;

while (l) {
    const value = array.shift();
    if (i % 3 === 0) array.push(value);
    l--;
    i++;
}

console.log(array);
```